# Join smail Dataframe with large in spark scala, removing duplicates with feature selection

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I have two DataFrame. Large with 19 millions rows and small with 180K rows.

Let's say in large DF I have next cols

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|               cuid                |    Col2    | Col3   |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
| 12654467                          | Value 1    |    123 |
| 164687948                         | Value 2    |    163 |
| 456132456                         | Value 3    |     45 |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

And in small DF next:

```
+-----------------------------------+
|               cuid                |   
+-----------------------------------+
| 12654467                          |
+-----------------------------------+
```

And output must be

```
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
|               cuid                |    Col2    | Col3   |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
| 12654467                          | Value 1    |    123 |
+-----------------------------------+------------+--------+
```

I've tried next

```
val joinedDF = smallDF.join(largeDF, Seq("cuid"), "inner")
```

But in joinedDF I have more, than 180K rows (6 millions). Can anybody know how solve this problem?

UPD - In large and in small DF I have duplicates by cuid, but they have different values in other columns, so I can't grouping by cuid.

So, I have next question - how I can do features selection with other cols and removing duplicates?

Comment: Maybe you have duplicates in column cuid in largeDF. Try to groupBy cuid largeDF and count, maybe it will be 6 million rows.

Comment: Yes, in large DF I have duplicates by id, but this duplicates have different values in other column and I can't grouping by cuid

Comment: @Jerdy As you are performing inner join your result will have `distinct count cuid <= 180k`. But `count   cuid` can exceed 180k because of duplicates in data.

Comment: You need to find out witch rows you in groups you should take after group by cuid. Maybe it should be last rows or another logic, try investigate what you want to get in the end.

Answer (score 1):

This work perfectly for me.

Let's define our input sources:

- `big.csv`

```
cuid,col2,col3
1,what,bye
2,word,random
3,like,random
4,why,this
5,hello,number
6,bye,train
7,music,word
8,duck,bag
9,car,noise
10,crying,baby
```

- `small.csv`

```
cuid
1
4
7
7
```

The code:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.*;
import scala.collection.Seq;

import java.io.Serializable;

public class Foo {

    private static final SparkSession spark = new SparkSession
            .Builder()
            .master("local[*]")
            .getOrCreate();

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dataset<BigRow> bigDataset = spark
                .read()
                .option("header", true)
                .csv(".\\resources\\big.csv")
                .as(Encoders.bean(BigRow.class));
        bigDataset.show();
        bigDataset.printSchema();
        Dataset<SmallRow> smallDataset  = spark
                .read()
                .option("header", true)
                .csv(".\\resources\\small.csv")
                .as(Encoders.bean(SmallRow.class));
        smallDataset.show();
        smallDataset.printSchema();


        Dataset<Row> joined = bigDataset
                .join(smallDataset, "cuid");
        joined.show();
    }

    private static class SmallRow implements Serializable {
        private String cuid;

        public SmallRow() {}

        public String getCuid() {
            return cuid;
        }

        public void setCuid(String cuid) {
            this.cuid = cuid;
        }

        public SmallRow withCuid(final String cuid) {
            this.cuid = cuid;
            return this;
        }
    }

    private static class BigRow implements Serializable {
        private String cuid;
        private String col2;
        private String col3;

        public BigRow() {}

        public String getCuid() {
            return cuid;
        }

        public void setCuid(String cuid) {
            this.cuid = cuid;
        }

        public String getCol2() {
            return col2;
        }

        public void setCol2(String col2) {
            this.col2 = col2;
        }

        public String getCol3() {
            return col3;
        }

        public void setCol3(String col3) {
            this.col3 = col3;
        }

        public BigRow withCuid(final String cuid) {
            this.cuid = cuid;
            return this;
        }

        public BigRow withCol2(final String col2) {
            this.col2 = col2;
            return this;
        }

        public BigRow withCol3(final String col3) {
            this.col3 = col3;
            return this;
        }
    }

}
```

my output is:

```
+----+-----+----+
|cuid| col2|col3|
+----+-----+----+
|   1| what| bye|
|   4|  why|this|
|   7|music|word|
|   7|music|word|
+----+-----+----+
```

Consider using `distinct` to remove duplicates

```
Dataset<Row> noDuplicates = joined
                .dropDuplicates("cuid");
        noDuplicates.show();
```

Hope this help. Thomas.